# nginx and memcached, returns "download" as an attachment and not html content

Tags: php, apache, caching, nginx, memcached

I've got nginx set up to serve html content straight from memcached but to fail over to PHP using our own backend (not a traditional set up hence the configuration) but whenever a page is set in PHP to be retrieved from memcached, nginx appears to find it but then just downloads a file called "download" with what looks like binary data inside.

this is the nginx.conf file, and it's built from source using enhanced memcached module.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
                root /var/www;
                index index.html;
        }
        location ~* \.php$ {
                root /var/www;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        access_log /path/to/access/log/access_log;
        error_log /path/to/error/log/error_log;
        root /u1/live/sites/public_html;

        location ~* \.(jpg|png|gif|css|js|swf|flv|ico|html|woff|ttf|svg|htm)$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @notcached;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location / {
                set $enhanced_memcached_key "$server_name$request_uri";
                enhanced_memcached_hash_keys_with_md5 on;
                enhanced_memcached_pass memcache.local:11211;
                error_page 404 = @notcached;
        }

        location @memcache {
                set $enhanced_memcached_key "$server_name$request_uri";
                enhanced_memcached_hash_keys_with_md5 on;
                enhanced_memcached_pass memcache.local:11211;
                error_page 404 = @notcached;
        }

        location @notcached {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/main/php/file/index.html;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This question is probably better for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying reason for that is that de the memcached results don't have an automatically associated mimetype, which means they get served as binary by default.

To fix it add the following directive to your @memcached location:

```
default_type text/html;
```

Comment: Hi, that worked, well, it stopped it coming through as a download, but now the content is being returned like this 

xœí=iwÛF’Ÿí÷ò:ô¼Hž$À›’¥y’,ÇžøPl9žl’§×$"@pˆb<þ5ûOö—mUwh ÅCÊØ»™Ã"ú¨®®®ª®ª¾ž|ýôÍéÅOçgd”Œ=rþþäå‹SRÓ­ÓFãéÅSò¯ç¯^£®“‹ˆú±›¸O½FãìuÔFIî7“É¤>iÕƒhØ¸xÛ¸AXV–?µD©Y·»vôð oðfìùñac0ˆÚ5,´ïQxXc~¿xå}ÇÌëÃ°>f
?n8æ#Þ£6üùZÓ~vâ%äÅéý
)c–P‚µ4ö{ê^Öþ¥½?ÖNƒqH×ôXXŸ0?9¬½8;<³‡lÏEÁ˜÷ëŸ™o»Î¯šžë_‘ˆy‡µ8™z,1–ÔÈ(bÎa­a²$a‘I¨Œã/R·âø×‡­z¯FÆÌvéazÐÑÆA\ÉÐLê‘YÒP2
Ùa-a7IÀf
KŠÄ ôÇj×gÐ¨[Á¸F8=I€5ÕoD°ÖX³ÉÆoôšÆVä†I#Ó( éÐõiD3Ÿ:iÌÌà×uœ%®Ë _ãÀ—ô5ê    

any suggestions why?

Comment: looks like memcached items are zlib compressed in PHP, I'd ideally like to keep it that way but is there a way to decompress via nginx?

Comment: I don't think you need to: browsers kan decompress gzipped html, but you need to signal that by adding `add_header Content-Encoding gzip;`to your memcached directives